# Unable to Connect SQL server with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Developed Codeigniter app with SQL server connection. it is properly connected when using PHP 5.6 on windows 7 PC, but same application not working on windows 10 with same PHP version. showing the error [image]

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.0.241',
'username' => 'sa',
'password' => 'mypw',
'database' => 'dbsrver',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt'  => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Comment: What is your server (or connection string) settings?

Comment: Please check again host / username /  password ..

Comment: Have you update php version as well? Please check configuration properly

Comment: Can you connect to your server with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: which one? on windows 10 if its.? yes, sql server is working properly

Comment: @Zhorov no it is on another server. but i access the 0.241 from another machine thats working. as i think this is the fault of my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some error in configuration. Make sure you have correctly configure database.
In application/config/databse.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'write password if any otherwise leave it empty',
    'database' => 'Your_Database_Name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: my configuration is ok i think, because same project working on another computer only the differant is it is windows 7, but it is not working on win 10 machine.